# React/Redux: Loading/merging all options and selected values

Tags: reactjs, redux

Using React and Redux...

I have an endpoint that returns the following model:

Name (String), and
Colors (Array)

And another endpoint that lists all the color options the user can choose from.

Now I want to make a multi-select that lists all the color options, which the appropriate ones selected based on what the first endpoint returns.

My questions are around how to best handle this.

1) Should I just instead create one endpoint that returns the model along with all the color options already included?

2) Or should I call both endpoints from one action creator, wait for both responses somewhere, then merge the data added a 'selected' property to those that should be selected?

3) Or something else?

Any help in how to design this would be much appreciated. Or a link to an example..I've searched and surprisingly can't find one.

Comment: That is an open question, all solutions are tradeoffs. There is no correct answer, only the one that is probably the most behaviorally consistent and causes the least amount of hurdles/issues for your **specific** application.

Comment: Can you include an example or two that just shows the data that flows from the app to the server and back? Like, "select purple" -> "get purple data from server" -> "server returns an array of objects with name and color keys". I'm having a hard time visualizing what exactly is going on besides suspecting you should fetch a list to load into the select input when the component loads. if the user selects a different option that changes the list, you can fetch that using an action creator or class method.